# Passing an image file from php to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a database in which there are images stored as LONGBLOB files. It seems I can't figure out how to "transport" those images to **JS** file so I could check their dimensions and compare them with the dimensions of the screen. Here is how I donwload the images:

```
function fillArrays(){
$idArray = array();
    $sql = "SELECT oglas_id,slika,prioriteta FROM deska WHERE deska.datumz <= CURRENT_DATE AND deska.datumk >= CURRENT_DATE;";
    $result = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['conn'],$sql);
    $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if($resultCheck>0){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            array_push($GLOBALS['idArray'],$row['oglas_id']);
            $image = base64_encode($row['slika']);    // THIS        "slika" means "image" in my lang...
            array_push($GLOBALS['imgArray'],$image);        //AND THIS
            array_push($GLOBALS['prArray'],$row['prioriteta']);
        }
    }else{
        die("Oops there seems to be an error(arr)");
    }
```

}

I am preety sure everything in lines of SQL is correct. The problem begins when I try to get the images stored in array into javascript. I am trying to do it by *json_encode*.

```
<script>
        var idArray = <?php echo json_encode($idArray) ?>;
        var imgArray = <?php echo json_encode($imgArray) ?>;
        var prArray = <?php echo json_encode($prArray) ?>;
    </script>
    <script src="includes/script.js"></script>
```

Then we jump to my javascript file ( script.js ). Now when I try to output the dimensions of the image selected, it says *undefined undefined* (width*height).
Here is how I try to obrain the info of the image selected.
in my **JS** file:

```
var imgArray = window.imgArray;

var img = new Image();
img = imgArray[0];
img.width;
img.height;
```

I am aware the questions has been asked many times but I can't seem to wrap my head around it so I figured I would supply you guys with my concrete problem.
Thanks to anyone who helps.

Since I dont think people fully understand:

Aim of the site:

- Download images from database.
- Resize them.(IMAGE CANNOT BE LARGER THAN HALF OF THE SCREEN SIZE)
- Place them in the 2x2 table.

Comment: You want to output the image itself or just the dimensions? If it's just dimensions pass only them. You're better off writing this as a REST call which delivers a binary payload, it's better architecture and smaller (rather than base64 encoding)

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón Outputting JSON to as JS variable will convert JSON to js Object automatically.

Comment: first try to load image. http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/learn-asynchronous-image-loading-javascript

Comment: @Justinas, yes i delete my bad comment.

Comment: is image fully loaded before you try to get width and height? try with: `img.onload = function(){alert( img.width+", "+img.height );};`

Comment: I think so. but thats the problem i dont really know.. thats my code.. you tell me xD

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for the loaded image.

```
img.onload = function () {
  alert(this.width + ' ' + this.height);
};
```

Btw, if you need to resize the image, why don't you pass the screen resolution to PHP and then, there, you do all your checks? It's easier, because if you do this from JS, it depends on user browser.

Answer (score 0):

Code for reading image data :

```
function readURL(input) {
    console.log(input.files);
       if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
           var reader = new FileReader();
           //alert(input.files[0]);
           reader.onload = function (e) {

               $('#image_source').attr('src', e.target.result);
           }

           reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
       }
}
```

Convert the fetched image to base64 :

```
var handleFileSelect = function(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files;
    var file = files[0];

    if (files && file) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function(readerEvt) {
            var binaryString = readerEvt.target.result;
            document.getElementById("hidden_id").value = btoa(binaryString);
        };

        reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
    }
};
```

Add listener for image input type :

```
if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
    document.getElementById('image_id').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
} else {
    alert('The File APIs are not fully supported in this browser.');
}
```

Hope it helps you.